# Correct way to rxjs observe with timeout

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observer-pattern, observers

I need to get an object from ReplaySubject, and should throw an error, if no object will occur in 5 seconds.

Do some code below (and it's working), but I'm willing to find more elegant solution.

```
const replaySubject = new ReplaySubject(1);

function objGet() {
   return replaySubject;
}

function objGetWithTimeout() {
    const timeout = 5000;

    let observed = false;
    const objObserver = objGet();

    objObserver
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(() => observed = true);

    return race(
      objObserver,
      timer(timeout)
        .pipe(map(() => {
            if (!observed) {
              throw new Error('timeout');
            }
          })
        )
    )
  }
```

function called in that way:

```
objGetWithTimeout()
   .pipe(catchError((err) => console.error('timeout') && throwError(err)))
   .subscribe((data) => console.log('obj received', data));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`timeoutWith()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/timeoutWith) operator:

```
objObserver
  .pipe(
    first(),
    timeoutWith(timeout, throwError(new Error('timeout'))),
  )
```

Comment: nice operator! will use it definitely! but looking on it and still can't get how to use it with race operator.

because I need not only the very first result, but reaction on each change.

I think, it's really not that you expect ))
```return race(
      objObserver,
      objObserver
        .pipe(
          first(), 
          timeoutWith(timeout, throwError('timeout'))
        )
    )
```

Comment: `timeoutWith` emits always when at least `timeout` elapsed since the previous emission. This means it will work on every change. However you need to be aware that the first `error` notification will dispose the chain.